# What is the proper number of threadpool for multiprocessing module in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Due to this great question with the remarkable answers here [how-to-use-threading-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python), make me doubt, **is the number of ThreadPool has some significant on speed or memory usage?**

For example, should the number of ThreadPool is mutiplied number of number of my CPU cores?
(I have two CPU cores, so I should make 4,8,12,.. ThreadPool?).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython, a `ThreadPool` (and `threading` in general) is mainly useful for I/O-bound tasks.
As a test, you should keep increasing the pool size until your speed/throughput stops increasing.

For CPU-bound tasks in Python (but not `numpy` or other extensions that release the GIL while doing their work) it would be better to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. In that case, I tend to use as many processes as the CPU has cores. This is the default when creating a `Pool` with `processes=None`. If you use more processes than you have cores, processes from the pool will be fighting over cores.

Comment: I see, does this mean either I/O. bound or CPU bound, we just use multiprocessing module and forget about "threading" module for any task we do concurrentcy or parallelis?